# convert date to string

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

I'm getting data from a stored procedure and wonder which is the easiest way to convert DateTime (or date) to string?

```
recipes.Add(new Recipe
                  {
                        RecipeId = reader.GetInt32(recipeIdIndex),
                        Name = reader.GetString(nameIndex),
                        Date = reader.GetDateTime(dateIndex), //Date is a string

                    });
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Other than the obvious .ToString() there are other options.  I would posit the question of "Why do you want to just convert the date to a string in your Recipe class?"  I would leave it a DateTime until the moment it needs to be displayed.

Comment: When I make Date a DateTime I get the message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte' to type 'System.String'." Recipe is a List, am I missing something? I cant get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to convert date to string is not do it at all.

If you have to store date time as strings use `DateTime.ToString("o")` or ISO8601 format `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt")` as SynXsiS suggested.

Make sure you know if date is in local or UTC time - you may need to adjust values before displaying to a user.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming reader.GetDateTime() is returning a c# DateTime object, all you need to do is call ToString() on it passing in arguments to format it how you like.

```
reader.GetDateTime(dateIndex).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.ttt")
```